# Select previous paragraph tag under multiple scenarios

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and wondering if there's an elegant way to select tags under two different DOM scenarios. I'm using jQuery to validate a form and add an error class to a paragraph tag (which bolds the text and highlights it in red) if the input value is empty. Some of the paragraph and input tags exist in the DOM like this:

```
<td><p>Name:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="field_name"></td>
```

While others exist like this:

```
<td><p>Name:</p><input type="text" name="field_name"></td>
```

My jQuery function so far looks like this:

```
$("#form_id").submit(function() {
    var answer = true;
    $(this).find(".required").map(function() {
        if(!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("p").addClass("form_error");
            answer = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("p").removeClass("form_error");
        }
    });
    return answer;
});
```

The key line is this:

```
$(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("p").addClass("form_error");
```

Which is an explicit selection of p tags under my first DOM scenario, but of course it fails on the second. I'm looking for a single line of code that will select p tags under both scenarios. I've been playing with `.prev("p")` but have not figured it out so far. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Posting some HTML that is a bit more complete would be helpful.

Comment: Additional info: The table with the <TD> rows listed in my question is nested inside another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text input and its title (the text inside the `<p>` tags) are the only two within a row you could use a selector like one of these:

```
$('.required').parents('tr:first').find('p').addClass('form_error');

$('.required').closest('tr').find('p').addClass('form_error');
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyaqp/2/